# Set code background colour in R markdown to PDF

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

When an `Rnw` file is converted to `PDF` with RStudio and `knitr`, the code blocks have a pleasant grey background colour (like they do here at SO). When I convert a `md` file to `PDF`, the background colour is white and I can't seem to change it. The knitr [code decoration option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) `background` is only for LaTeX and has no effect in `md`.

How can I set a background colour for code blocks in the `PDF` I get from my `md` file? I see in some related questions that editing the markdown.css file might be relevant, but I'm not sure if that applies here since there's no html file in between the `md` and `PDF` files.

This effect can be reproduced using the knitr examples: [Rnw source: knitr-minimal.Rnw](https://raw.github.com/yihui/knitr/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) and [markdown source: 001-minimal.Rmd](https://raw.github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/master/001-minimal.Rmd).

To convert `Rnw` to `PDF` I just click the 'compile PDF' button in RStudio. Here's what I do to convert `md` to `PDF`:

```
# Load packages
require(knitr)
require(markdown)

setwd("C:/Users/.../Desktop/")

# Process .md and .pdf files
filen <- "myfile"
knit(paste0(filen,".md"))
system(paste0("pandoc -s ", paste0(filen,"-out.md"), " -t latex -o ", paste0(filen,".pdf")))
```

Is there another way to convert `md` to `PDF` so I can get a coloured code background?

Comment: for the `system()` command, that is what the `pandoc()` function is for: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/

Comment: Thanks for checking in! Can we have an option to supply panodoc arguments to your pandoc function? Rather than having a config file or embedding config in the md file (or does that defeat the purpose of your function...)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I may need to think about it. In that case, I guess `system()` and `pandoc()` require approximately the same typing effort, so feel free to go with `system()` :)

Comment: Well, it's just a minor detail, and does not detract at all from the brilliance that is your `knitr` package. For me (and I'm sure many others), it's packages like `knitr`, `ggplot2`, `plyr` and `data.table` that make a huge improvement to the versatility, accessibility and appeal of `R`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're already set up with Pandoc, you should be able to achieve this using Pandoc's `--highlight-style` argument. From the [docs](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html):

> --highlight-style=STYLE Specifies the coloring style to be used in highlighted source code. Options are pygments (the default), kate,
>   monochrome, espresso, zenburn, haddock, and tango.

If you're not specifying the language that each code block contains within the markdown file, you might also have to set the `--indented-code-classes` argument:

> --indented-code-classes=CLASSES Specify classes to use for indented code blocks–for example, perl,numberLines or haskell. Multiple classes
>   may be separated by spaces or commas.

From memory, I think this might require a latex package like `fancyvrb`, so you might have to install that before it works.

Comment: Yep, that's done the job, thanks. I found that --indented-code-classes wasn't necessary, nor fancyvrb (unless I installed it previously and forgot about it).

Answer (score 6):

Marius' answer is exactly what I was after. Since comments can't take images, I'm pasting a few screenshots here in case others are curious about this.

To get code backgrounds in the `PDF` generated from the `md`, I adjusted my code like so:

```
# Load packages
require(knitr)
require(markdown)

setwd("C:/Users/.../Desktop/")

# Create .md and .pdf files
filen <- "test"
knit(paste0(filen,".md"))
system(paste0("pandoc -s ", paste0(filen,"-out.md"), " -t latex -o ", paste0(filen,".pdf"), " --highlight-style=tango -S"))
```

In testing the seven `pandoc` highlighting options, I found that only three give code backgrounds. Here are screenshots of the PDFs generated with each of the three options, for future reference.

This is tango, the one that best matches what I'm after with the light grey:

[image]
And this is zenburn:
[image]
And this is espresso
[image]