# Grey shading around compiled r markdown document to MS word

Tags: r, ms-word

When I compile a R Markdown document to a word document there is this grey shading around the r code when I print. I tried all the features I can think of in MS word and R studio to removes this without success. The question is..

How can I remove this grey shading around my r code when compiling a R markdown document to MS word?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17270262/322912)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes but I want to remove the code background and not add or change it

Comment: Have you tried different highlight styles? I wonder if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41030920/322912) would work...

Comment: @RomanLuštrik that works if I compile an html doc but not a ms word doc

Comment: I had the same problem and found an answer in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862802/rmarkdown-how-to-remove-grey-background-on-output).

Answer (score -1):

Mark the code in Word, press shift and F1. This brings up the formating menu for the text. The text and the abstract are fomated with a light grey background. Both have to be changed to white or to transparent.