# Rmarkdown - how to remove grey background on output

Tags: r-markdown

I am experiencing a slightly irritating problem, which is that I am not able to remove the grey text from output (please see picture below).

I've searched for a solution, but is restricted by my lack of knowledge about the proper terms, and therefore I am not able to find any solutions.

I know this can be somehow bypassed by using only one "`", yet I need the triple "```" in order to run my code interpreting rows.

[The grey background on output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cMWl.jpg)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
hej <- ("test")
print(hej)
```
````

Comment: _Note_: I've added an important comma to `{r, echo=FALSE}` in your second R chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might simply want to override the grey highlighting in the YAML header as follows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
   word_document:
      highlight: NULL
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Now if you want to get rid of the "##" and the line-numbers, tell knitr to handle texts as-is, and use `cat()`:

````
```{r textfoo, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
hej <- ("test")
cat(hej)
```
````

Et voilà:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply - this worked out like a charm.
I've also managed to remove the ## from the code.

Yet whenever I print information there is an [1] in front of the code.
Do you, by any chance, know how to remove it. Or can you direct me towards what terms I should search for?

Comment: You need to use use `results = 'asis'`  in chunk options and `cat(hej)` in the code. I've edited my answer accordingly.